# Problem Loading Jupyter Notebook in Windows 10 Pro

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, windows-10

I am new in Anaconda (Jupyter Notebbok) and training python. After I installed Anconda when I open Jupyter notebook, the program won't be loaded.
**First** I run 'jupyter notebook' from the 'command prompt':
[image]

**Second**, when InterneTExplorer loaded and then I click the New>Python3
[image]
Finally I expected to have 'jupyter notebook' to  write python codes, but I see  below picture:
[image]

**Desired Page:**
[image]
Can you help me to find the reason for the problem?
In the following link I have attached a video from my Desktop view.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDvYwHlvghI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to open the file from the terminal? Create an empty file. In terminal, go to that empty file directory and open that empty file from terminal in Jupyter notebook. Then try to create new .ipynb inside of that file. Just another way to test if it's browser issue or Anaconda download issue.
Command for terminal-
~cd file directory
~jupyter notebook
It will automatically open the Jupyter in your web browser from your terminal.

Comment: Thank you, the problem solved by change in  web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the 'localhost' link from command prompt in the Firefox browser and solved the problem.

[image]